# "docker build -f" command does not seem to progress and shows no error

Tags: tomcat, docker, dockerfile

Docker newbie here.

Installed Docker toolbox in Windows 7.

Have a '`.df`' to create a Tomcat image.This file has all the required commands.

In the '*Docker Quick start terminal*' typed on the below command

```
docker build -f tomcat.df -t demo/tomcat:8 .
```

There seems to be no progress or no error.

Please share any fix to resolve this issue.

Comment: How large is `.`, including all files in all subdirectories?

Comment: Yup...  thanks..  now realize that the Docker Quick Start Terminal is picking up files from my Windows directory "C:\Users\username"  by default..    unable to figure out the command to change this directory or to pickup the .df file from another directory say "D:\dockerfiles"..  plz let me know if any solution for this issue....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first step of a docker build is to package up the build context and send it to the docker server (it's a client/server app even if you're running locally). All of the `COPY` and `ADD` commands are done with this context, not your workstation's filesystem, since the build could be run on another system. Once the context is done being zipped up and sent to the server you'll start to see some output.

So if you see a long delay without any output from the docker build command, look into reducing the size of this context. Don't include any unnecessary directories and files, and don't make some top level directory your context. It's possible that your context could be sent until you run out of disk space if your context includes the temporary folder docker uses to receive that context on the host.

You indicate the directory of your build context as the last argument to the build, often a single `.` to indicate the current directory. To pass a different directory for your context, you can `cd` to the other location, or provide a different path instead of the `.`.

Note that the Dockerfile location is relative to the build context and should be included in your context. You can also exclude files from the build context by including a `.dockerignore` file with a syntax similar to `.gitignore` in the root of your build context.